# View Windows 7 BCD Settings

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, bcd, bcdedit

I recently ran the command `bcdedit /set {default} bootstatuspolicy ignoreallfailures` to ignore Windows Startup Repair.

I would now like to verify that this option was set in BCD. How can I go about verifying this?

I've tried `bcdedit /enum all` but I can't find the information I'm after. I just want to verify that `bootstatuspolicy` is set to `ignoreallfailures`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After rebooting my workstation the setting shows up after running `bcdedit /enum all` under the **Windows Boot Loader** section.

```
Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 7
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {efbc007d-bbea-11e1-b4d9-9e0b0aef12a6}
recoveryenabled         Yes
testsigning             No
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {efbc007b-bbea-11e1-b4d9-9e0b0aef12a6}
nx                      OptIn
bootstatuspolicy        IgnoreAllFailures
```

Answer (score 1):

You can examine the complete contents of Windows 7 BCD using
[Visual BCD Editor](http://www.boyans.net).

You can also change existing values of loader elements and create new ones comfortably in a visual environment.